# jQuery callback function not waiting for completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with a multiple DIV menu system. I have 3 divs for 3 separate displays on the same page. By default the "about" div displays. When you click Contact or Resume, the About div should slide up before either of the other divs slide down. Clicking other menu choices will have the same result.

Here's the basic layout of the page:

```
<div id="menutabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" name="divAbout"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="divContact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="divResume"><span>Résumé</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the container divs have IDs that match the link names.

The jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("#"+divname).siblings(".contentbox").slideUp("slow", function() {
        $("#"+divname).slideDown("slow");
    });
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that I wrote the code with only 2 divs on the page and it worked perfect. The callback function did not execute until the first div was done sliding up. However, when I added a 3rd div, it no longer waits.

I have commented out multiple divs to confirm that the issue was specifically just having 3 divs on the page, as it didn't act this way no matter which 2 divs I left uncommented.

Any ideas?

Comment: I should probably note that the divs all share a class of "contentbox", which is why the jQuery looks for that class of siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that the callback is invoked *once for each element*.

So if there are 10 `.contentbox` elements getting the `slideUp`, you're firing the `slideDown` method on `'#' + divname' 10 times. This can cause unexpected problems.

To avoid this, you can use a simple variable as a flag.

```js
$("a").click(function () {
    var divname = this.name;
    var has_run = false;
    $("#"+divname).siblings(".contentbox").slideUp("slow", function() {
        if( !has_run ) {
            $("#"+divname).slideDown("slow");
            has_run = true;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Another solution would be to use a `setTimeout` in place of the callback for `slideUp`.

```js
$("a").click(function () {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("#"+divname).siblings(".contentbox").slideUp("slow");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#"+divname).slideDown("slow");
    }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it's because the function goes through and checks all the siblings... It executed the code for the open siblings, but when it came to closed siblings it interpreted that as the function being complete. 

Your first example didn't work, but the setTimeout function worked much smoother than the delay(600) workaround I was using. Still not perfect, but much much better.

Comment: @one800higgins: You're welcome. I'm surprised that the first example didn't work. The code inside the `if( !has_run )` should only run once. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
 .delay()
```

use values in millis for better timing

```
$("#"+divname).siblings(".contentbox").slideUp(200).delay(300).end().slideDown(200);
```

for example

Comment: Yea, that was my first idea... But it's just not as clean looking. User "am not i am" had a better delay idea with setTimeout() that works smoother in this scenario.

Comment: ok, i would recommend store jquery object in a varible to save 1 dom search  /// var $div =$("#"+divname);